# Internal Server Error When POST to Marketing Cloud create contact REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest

I am getting an internal server error when trying to save a contact in Marketing Cloud with Rest API.

The body of my request is:

```
{
    "contactKey": "acruz@example.com",
    "attributeSets": [
        {
            "name": "Email Addresses",
            "items": [
                {
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "Email Address",
                            "value": "acruz@example.com"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My end point is: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/contacts/v1/contacts

I use postman for tests, and I am getting this error:

```
{
    "documentation": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm",
    "errorcode": 0,
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Thank for your answers.

Comment: Try with a different email address

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already got the Access token from your SFMC integration App

Please Use below and replace YOUR_SUBDOMAIN and YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN values with your values

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /contacts/v1/contacts
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
{
    "contactKey": "acruz@example.com",
    "attributeSets": [{
                      "name": "Email Addresses",
                      "items": [{
                         "values": [{
                             "name": "Email Address",
                             "value": "acruz@example.com"
                                   }]
                              }]
                       }]
}
```

Comment: Hi Pardeep! I do it and I have the same error.